# stat function returns empty struct

Tags: c, file, directory, stat

```
studentsDir = opendir(lineValues);
while ((entry = readdir(studentsDir)) != NULL) {
    stat(path, &dirData);
    if (S_ISDIR(dirData.st_mode) && (entry->d_name[0] != '.')
            && (entry->d_name[1] != '.')) {
```

Im searching in a directory for folders. The problem is that stat returns  dirdata with empty values for most of the folders

Comment: Check the return value of stat() and possibly check errno.  Otherwise, does the program have permissions to check the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code needs:

```
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
```

the prototype for the function is:

```
  int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

so you also need:

```
struct stat dirData;
```

and the *path variable needs to be the actual path (can be relative or absolute), with the file name, to the target file.

Nothing in the posted code indicates any of the above has been included in the code.

and 'entry' is a pointer to a 'struct dirent' where the current file/directory name needs to be appended to 'path' before stat() uses it.

'entry' needs to be checked to assure it is not NULL before using it.

the struct dirent contains the d_name[256] field that will contain
the name of a current file (or directory) (but not the whole path)
so each time the code steps into a (sub) directory,
(which the posted code is not doing)
then the path needs to have the string from d_name[] 
appended to the path string